# Selectivizr and CSS on a CDN does not work

Tags: css, cdn, polyfills, css-selectors, selectivizr

When I reference CSS and selectivizr.js on a CDN, the :last-child pseudo class does not work. If however, I reference just selectivizr.js on the CDN and the CSS locally, the pseudo class works. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

From [selectivirz.com](http://selectivizr.com/):

> Style sheets MUST be hosted on the same domain as the page due to browser security restrictions. Likewise, style sheets loaded using the `file:` protocol will not work.